# How to remove x axis from bar graph in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, graph, axis

I would like to remove x and y-axis from bar graph in Matlab, but x-axis is still visible and I can't find the reason why.

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5];

b = bar(x);

axis off
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually the 'baseline' of the bar() function.

Use `set(b,'ShowBaseLine','off');` to turn it off.